# Converting SAS Proc Shewhart into R programming

Tags: r, sas

I have a data, where SAS `Proc shewhart` is implemented, I want to implement the same in R program, below is the data and sas code

```
> valueid   date     dis_id sales_amount    yymm (year month)
> 868       5-Mar-18    2   956             1803
  868       6-Apr-17    2   473             1704
  868       22-Dec-16   2   524             1612
  914       17-Dec-15   2   1768            1512
  914       18-Aug-16   2   477             1608
  914      12-Jan-17    2   804             1701
  870       1-May-17    2   1373            1705
  870       8-Sep-17    2   323             1709
  870      29-Feb-16    2   1718            1602
  870      26-Jan-16    2   1242            1601
  870       1-Apr-16    2   995             1604
  800      22-Apr-16    2   356             1604
  925      10-May-16    2   1487            1605
  928      30-May-16    2   1210            1605
  928      29-Jun-16    2   1935            1606
  928      28-Nov-16    2   1149            1611
  928      13-Dec-16    2   835             1612
  987      10-Jul-17    2   1023            1707
  987      27-Jul-17    2   389             1707
  987      22-Sep-17    2   1191            1709
```

Below is the Program use to implement `XSCHART`

`proc shewhart data=sales_revenue; 
   by valueid; 
   xschart sales_amount*yymm/ nochart outtable= newoutput; 
   id dis_id; 
 run;`

I need to convert this shewhart  with `xschart` into R. kindly help me.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service.  What research have you done regarding creating control charts in R?

Comment: I have provided the code for the reference, if any member have idea, they can refer that how i implement in the SAS.  Till now I have find that QCC is a package in R, which can be use to implement control charts, but identically i need the the output in terms of dataframe. not as a chart.